# Can I swap WCF deserializer from configuration?

Tags: wcf, configuration, serialization, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

I have a problem with WCF deserialization where [the client hangs on the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876955/wcf-client-hangs-on-response/2904133#2904133) for more than a minute.

I'd like to try to swap different deserializers and see if it affects the behavior.

Can I swap in/out different serializers (are there any others?) **from configuration**, and if so can I do that with any binding, or is that out of control once the service reference is imported?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I swap in/out different
>   serializers (are there any others?)
>   **from configuration**

[This](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/04/10/specifying-a-different-serializer-per-endpoint-in-wcf/) describes how to use the XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer on two different endpoints for the same service. Its not exactly swapping them in and out but it might suffice for your testing.

Comment: thx but your link seems to be showing how to expose the same service through different endpoints in a hosting scenario - my question is more about a WCF client consuming a given service and using different kinds of deserialization